# Optimizing mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am running a flask app with mysql db.

I have 400000 records in a table and there is a query (insert with select) that takes around 3 seconds if run single.

But when I tried to load test it by hitting the api with multiple requests at a time (like 20 hits at a time, 50 and 100 hits at a time), the response for all requests coming at once. For example, if total 100 concurrent requests takes around 3 mins, then all those individual requests are starting immediately but giving response after 3 mins only (instead of 3 or 4 seconds).

Also, I tried with 1 gb ram server, 4 gb ram server and also 32 gb ram server with 16 cpus. Here is the response as below:

```
# 4GB RAM, 2 CPUS server with only Mysql installed in it
Total time is: 0:05:29.752275 (all 100 requests getting response after 5 mins(total time), not 3 or 4 seconds)
successful: 89
Failed: 11
Tried: 100


# 32 GB RAM, 16 CPUs server with only Mysql installed in it
Total time is: 0:05:17.119773 (all 100 requests getting response after 5 mins(total time), not 3 or 4 seconds)
successful: 86
Failed: 14
Tried: 100
```

So, if you see, both 4gb and 32gb servers has almost no difference in performance. So it seems like something totally wrong with my setup/configuration/query.

More details:

I ran another script where I directly hit db in the script without any api. This way, even though server has 4gb RAM, mysql server dying(segmentation fault and also mysql server dies) for just 3 concurrent requests.

But then I gave like 0.2, 0.3 and 0.5 milli seconds delay between each hit/thread so the results were slighly meaningful. Each request used to take total time but with 0.5 ms delay between each hit, each request completing in less than 10 seconds.

Can I do anything so my server easily returns response fast for atleast 100 concurrent requests without any gap between requests(and is that necessary?)

Any thoughts on what to do here?

Comment: When running 20, are you inserting into the _same_ table?  What 'engine' is the table?

Answer (score 1):

I think the root cause is flask. Flask is not good in multi-process/thread at all.

I meet this problem before, then change to `Tornado` and use `supervisord` to keep Tornado as daemon mode.

another solution is `Gunicorn` => https://intellipaat.com/community/12737/how-to-run-flask-with-gunicorn-in-multithreaded-mode

Comment: Agree on  gunicorn+flask or uwsgi (if you have time to learn how to properly configure it)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, "atleast 100 concurrent requests without any gap" is not realistic.  The user goes to the client, which connects to the database, which takes queries rapidly, but not really simultaneously.  That is, in real life queries rarely start simultaneously.

Also, if you have the configuration (MySQL's `max_connections`) and/or the corresponding setting in the client too high, then you are asking for the "thundering herd" syndrome.  It's like being in an over-crowded grocery store and you can't move your cart because all the space is taken.

More specifically, 16 CPUs will stumble over each other vying for resources when you throw 100 queries into the mix "concurrently".

As for inserting a lot of rows, there are several techniques.

- `LOAD DATA` is very fast.
- "Batched `INSERT`" is fast.  This is where a single `INSERT` has lots of records.  I often see 10x speedup with 100 rows at a time. (versus single-row inserts)
- `BEGIN...COMMIT` around a bunch of single-row inserts.  This avoids some of the "transaction" overhead.
- Avoid `UNIQUE` indexes (other than the `PRIMARY KEY`) on the table you are loading.
- Ping-ponging staging tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table -- this allows multiple clients to rapidly feed data in.